# How to generate a state/province dropdown that selects the value in the database

Tags: php, mysql, html

So I have several places for country and state/province dropdowns. What I'd like to do is have a function for each of these and when I run my while loop on customer data from mysql I want to select the right  by default from the data in the database.

Reason is right now the dropdowns default to the HTML selected one so if users don't change it to theirs again when they edit their account they re-save their info with the wrong state/country.

I'd also like to use this in several places so I want a big array of countries and states/provinces that loop.

Just looking for a hand or be pointed to where this has been done in a function already.

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

`$states` - query with all states, `$user_state` - current user's state. So your user's choice will be selected by default.

```
<?php
echo '<select name="state">';
while ($state = mysql_fetch_assoc($states))
{
  echo '<option value="' . $state['state'] . '"';
  if ($user_state == $state['state'])
  {
    echo ' selected';
  }
  echo '>' . $state . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Smashing, thank you. This worked flawlessly with my state array.